# date in newspaper articles

Tags: biblatex

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            style=authoryear,%
            mergedate=basic,
            ]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Article{frie2002,
  author =   {Jonathan Friedland},
  title =    {Across the Divide},
  journal =  {Guardian},
  year =     {2002},
  pages =    {10-11},
  date =     {2002-01-15},
  volume =   {section G2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib} 
\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output it produces is

[image]

How do I get this output?

[image]

Comment: I've changed the question a bit as I've found out about `mergedate=basic` and the `date` field.  So now I suppose the issue is more about the formatting of 'date' in articles.

Comment: Partial solution: 1) Use the opiton `dateabbrev = false` in order to fully spell out “January”. 2) Put “section G2” in the field `note` instead of `volume`. I’m not sure if `volume` would be appropriate at any rate, and `note` is put in the position where you want it. What’s _missing_ here is 1) it’s “January 15“ instead of “15 January” and 2) the date is in parentheses (plus surrounding punctuation). Btw, nice MWE! :)

Comment: I agree with doncherry that you wouldn't put `section G2` into the `volume` field. It could be `chapter`, I suppose, but `note` would also be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `entrysubtype = {newspaper}` to distinguish newspaper articles form journal articles.

An entry would look like this (we use `chapter` instead of `volume` which didn't seem right)

```
@article{frie2002,
  author  = {Jonathan Friedland},
  title   = {Across the Divide},
  journal = {Guardian}, 
  pages   = {10-11},
  date    = {2002-01-15},
  chapter = {section G2}, 
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
```

We can then modify several macros and check for `newspaper`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{chapter}{\ifnumerals{#1}{\bibstring{chapter}~}{}#1}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{newspaper:issue+date}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
     \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
     \usebibmacro{issue}}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{newspaper:issue+date}{%
  \printtext{%
    \iffieldundef{day}{}{%
      \mkdatezeros{\thefield{day}}%
      \iffieldundef{month}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{month}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{month}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}
    {\printfield{chapter}}{}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            style=authoryear,%
            mergedate=basic,
            ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{frie2002,
  author  = {Jonathan Friedland},
  title   = {Across the Divide},
  journal = {Guardian}, 
  pages   = {10-11},
  date    = {2002-01-15},
  chapter = {section G2}, 
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{chapter}{\ifnumerals{#1}{\bibstring{chapter}~}{}#1}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{newspaper:issue+date}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
     \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
     \usebibmacro{issue}}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{newspaper:issue+date}{%
  \printtext{%
    \iffieldundef{day}{}{%
      \mkdatezeros{\thefield{day}}%
      \iffieldundef{month}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{month}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{month}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{newspaper}
    {\printfield{chapter}}{}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document} 
\nocite{frie2002,sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> Friedland, Jonathan (2002), “Across the Divide”, in: Guardian, 15 Jan., section G2, pp. 10–11.
>
> Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998), “Comparison of methods for deriving
> atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”, in: Journal
> of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-
> 987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.

Comment: Great: thanks.  Adding `dateabbrev = false` as an option (thanks @doncherry and @dudakl ) spells out January in full.

Comment: @GarethWalker Yes. I didn't want to make the output inconsistent by forcing the long string here regardless of the `dateabbrev` setting.

Answer (score 1):

A maybe ugly, but working solution would be:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            style=authoryear,%
            dateabbrev=false
            ]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Article{frie2002,
  author =   {Jonathan Friedland},
  title =    {Across the Divide},
  journal =  {Guardian},
  year =     {2002},
  pages =    {10-11},
  date =     {2002-01-15},
  volume =   {section G2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib} 

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{\printfield{journaltitle},}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\printfield{day}. \mkbibmonth{\printfield{month}}, #1}


\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Produces the desired output on my machine:[image: desired-reference style]

But I have to admit, this seems to be a somewhat strange way of layouting your references ;)

Comment: Thanks. I agree it's strange, but required in the style I am trying to work to (MHRA).

Comment: Please note that this method destroys the output for other `@article`s, that is probably not what you want.

Comment: As @moewe pointed out, my solution changes all `@article` elements in your .bib. 
But as far as I understand the MHRA-style-guide, you just have to put all references  _"in alphabetical order by 
names  of  author(s)  or  editor(s),  followed  by  date  of  publication."_ , the "authoryear"-option should be sufficient...